# Can multiple threads join the same boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

[`pthreads`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) has undefined behavior if multiple threads try to join the same thread:

> If multiple threads simultaneously try to join with the same thread,
>          the results are undefined.

Is the same true for [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html)s? The documentation does not appears to specify this.

If it is undefined, then what would be a clean way for multiple threads to wait on one thread completing?

Comment: Hmm, interestingly, it is not mentioned in the N4296 C++ standard draft that I can read. I would say it is then UB and/or "don't do it" kind of behaviour. :)

Comment: Other threads could test if a thread was `joinable()`, or the closing thread could use `condition_variable` to signal all its work is finished (even though it _may_ be still running)

Comment: @wilx, `std::thread::join()` is a non-const function, therefore calling it concurrently is a data race, i.e. undefined behaviour. That rule applies to all standard library types unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @Tas, if two threads call `joinable()` concurrently what is to stop both of them then trying to call `join()`? Even if only one calls `join()`, without some kind of synchronization that `join()` call conflicts with the `joinable()` call in the other thread, leading to a data race, i.e. undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> If it is undefined, then what would be a clean way for multiple threads to wait on one thread completing?

The clean way would be for that one thread to inform the others that it is complete. A `packaged_task` contains a `future` which can be waited on, which can help us here.

Here's one way of doing that. I have used std::thread and std::packaged_task, but you could use the boost equivalents just as well.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void emit(const char* msg) {
    static std::mutex m;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto one_task = std::packaged_task<void()>([]{
        emit("waiting...");
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(500));
        emit("wait over!");
    });

    // note: convert future to a shared_future so we can pass it
    // to two subordinate threads simultaneously
    auto one_done = std::shared_future<void>(one_task.get_future());
    auto one = std::thread(std::move(one_task));

    std::vector<std::thread> many;
    many.emplace_back([one_done] {
        one_done.wait();
        // do my thing here
        emit("starting thread 1");
    });

    many.emplace_back([one_done] {
        one_done.wait();
        // do my thing here
        emit("starting thread 2");
    });

    one.join();
    for (auto& t : many) {
        t.join();
    }

    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
waiting...
wait over!
starting thread 2
starting thread 1
Hello, World
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `boost::condition_variable`... roughly:

```
class thread_wrapper {
    boost::mutex mutex;
    boost::condition_variable thread_done_condition;
    bool thread_done = false;

    void the_func() {
        // ...
        // end of the thread
        {  
            boost:unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
            thread_done = true;
        }
        thread_done_condition.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_until_done() {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        thread_done_condition.wait(lock, [this]{ return thread_done; });
    }
}
```

Then multiple callers can safely call `wait_until_done()`.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me now that something like the following would also have worked:

```
class thread_wrapper {
public:
    thread_wrapper() : thread([this]() { this->the_func(); }) { }

    void wait_until_done() {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(join_mutex);
        thread.join();
    }

private:
    void the_func() {
        // ...
    }

    boost::mutex join_mutex;
    boost::thread thread;
}
```